# Is it possible to find a sequence to make all values 1 for a graph where nodes with binary values have exactly 2 directed incoming and outgoing edges

Tags: graph-theory

Hello everyone I asked this question here before, but I would like to share it again.

Imagine a graph with N nodes and each node has exactly 2 leaving directed edges and 2 incoming directed edges. Each node can take values {0,1}.

Now here is the catch, at the start all nodes have value 0 . You can visit a node however you like but when you visit a node it's value and it's connected nodes with 1 edge changes their values. Is it possible to follow a sequence where one makes all nodes values 1.

For example:

There is a graph like:

```
Nodes = {A,B,C,D,E}
Edges = {A -> B, A -> C,  
         B -> C, B -> D, 
         C -> D, C -> E, 
         D -> E, D -> A,
         E -> A, E -> B }
```

Now when we follow sequence {A,B,C,D,E} values of each node will be as follows:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

As you can see at last visit all nodes became 1.

So what I want to figure out is, is it possible to find a sequence for all possible graphs generated by the rules mentioned above?

How can I prove or disprove this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To clarify: (1) Is it correct that when you visit a node $v$, then the values change at three nodes: $v$ and both nodes $w$ with an arc $v \to w$? (2) Can you visit nodes in any order, or do you have to follow the edges in the graph?

Comment: @MishaLavrov (1) correct. In the example when I visit node A, A,B and C nodes changed their values. (2) Yes you can visit nodes in any order and as many times as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some graphs may have shorter solutions, but visiting every node once will always work (with the conditions you've specified). Each node will change its value three times: once when you visit that node, and once when you visit the source of each of its incoming edges. So the value of that node will go from $0$ to $1$ to $0$ to $1$.

For an example of a graph where a shorter solution exists, consider the graph with nodes $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ and twelve edges:

- The six edges $A \to B$, $B \to C$, $C \to D$, $D \to E$, $E \to F$, $F \to A$;
- The six edges $A \to C$, $B \to D$, $C \to E$, $D \to F$, $E \to A$, $F \to B$.

Then visiting nodes $A$ and $D$ is enough to toggle all six nodes, due to the edges $A \to B, A \to C, D \to E, D \to F$.

Comment: First I am really grateful for your answer it helps a lot. So what I understand from your answer is any randomly generated graph with respect to the conditions I specified will have a sequence to make all nodes 1. All I have to do is visit each node once and that's it? I mean the examples we gave are pretty straight forward. I am curious if it will hold with all possible edge combinations. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, it will always hold: the hard part is making sure that every node has two edges going into it. (In fact, as long as every node has an *even number* of edges going into it, visiting all the nodes will work.)